# Как сделать, чтобы display:block был ровно по ширине ссылки?

Tags: html, css

Например, `<a href="">Text</a>`.
Если для этой ссылки задать display:block, то оно будет во всю ширину. Как сделать, чтобы ссылка была блочной ровно по тексту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если попробовать inline-block?

Comment: Сработало правило: `inherit`

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от ситуации. display: inline-block или float используйте, только clearfix не забудьте.